# How do I configure an .osx file?

Tags: macos

I have found the following repository on GitHub...

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx

...that has some useful environmental settings I would like to adopt.  It appears they go into a .osx file.  Where is this file located?  Also, when does it 'run'?  Do I have to reboot the machine to get the settings in this to be recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a shell script that is missing the shebang at the top of the file.

It could be that it is intended to be copied into an existing script to provide OS X-specific functionality so the main script can be portable (I'd expect there to be dotfiles for other operating systems, as well.)

On the other hand, it could be intended as a file of ideas and you pick the ones you want and paste them into your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 4):

Select settings that look interesting, paste them in a terminal, and then quit and reopen applications to try them out.

You might also save the whole script as for example `~/.osx` and then run `bash ~/.osx` in a terminal. It includes commands for things like changing the computer name though.

The defaults commands modify files like `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`, and you only have to run them once. Adding them to .bash_profile would only make your shell startup time longer. You might keep a personal file like .osx though in case you make a clean installation of OS X. And for example `chflags nohidden ~/Library` has to be run again after every OS X update.

I have a file like .osx only for settings that can't be changed from the UI ([defaults.txt](http://lri.me/files.html)). I think it's easier to transfer settings to new OS X installations by recreating them manually, by copying the plist files, or by using Migration Assistant.